# How can I get true if there is at least one specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
 user_due_diligence
```

| user_id | cellphone | national_id | postal_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | approved | in_progress | in_progress |
| 5 | in_progress | approved | not_investigated |
| 5 | approved | not_investigated | not_investigated |

I want to get 1 row per `user_id` and either `0` or `1` if there is at least one `approved` record or not. So **the expected result is**:

| user_id | cellphone | national_id | postal_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Any idea how can I do that?

---

I know the query should include `group by user_id`, and `case when x = "approved"`, but I don't know the exact syntax.

Comment: `MAX( IF cellphone = 'approved', 1, 0) ` and so on for other fields with a `GROUP BY user_id` should work. Provide a fiddle if you want a complete working example

Comment: Because MySQL returns 1 or 0 for boolean expressions already, this could be shortened: `MAX(cellphone = 'approved')`

Answer (score 0):

in this query I used `SUM()` and `CASE WHEN` to match the cases when `cellphone`, `national_id` or `postal_code` equals `approved` when it's true I add 1 to the summary for each one of them, and at the end you need to `group by` the `user_id` to get one result per `user_id`.

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(CASE When cellphone LIKE 'approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cellphone ,   
SUM(CASE When national_id like 'approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS national_id ,
SUM(CASE WHEN postal_code like 'approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS postal_code
FROM user_due_diligence
GROUP BY user_id;
```